# what is "unfortunately app has stopped" error means

Tags: android

I have recently started learning andriod development. I have a problem with my android app that is when I lunch it on the emulater it gets successfully lunched but when I click on my app it gets stopped by giving the error " unfortunately app has stopped " . One thing that I have noticed that a simple hello app with a single text view works fine and gets successful run on emulater ...
I m working on os x10.8.6 . I have eclipse 4.2.0 . Plz give me solution ...

Comment: This is caused because you have an error on your app, look at your logcat and/or debug the activity. If after that you still do not know what is happening post your code / layout and logcat and be more specific about which is your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very `broad scope` question, but I will try to give you a overview about it.

There can be several reasons for a `Force Close`. Most of the time it occurs if some exception or error occured while the apps was executing. One of the most commons mistakes made by the beginners which cause force close is they haven't added activity in `Android Manifest` and try to start the new activity.

There are several other reasons for this problem. If you are facing such a problem in your app, post your code here. We might be able to help properly then.